# C# keep drawed images with Graphics.DrawImage

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, panel, draw

I am trying to draw images on a panel with a click event.I managed to do that,but I want to keep the generated images.After each click,the previously generated image disapears.How can I keep all the drawed images?
This is my code untill now:

```
private void drawdot(object sender,PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Image dot = Image.FromFile("dot.png");
            var points = this.PointToClient(new Point(Cursor.Position.X-20, Cursor.Position.Y-30));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(dot, points);
        }


private void grid2_Paint(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(started==true)
            {
                var points = this.PointToClient(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y));
                coord2.Add(points.ToString());
                clickuri2++;
                test2_puncte.Text = "Testul 2 | Puncte: " + clickuri2;
                //draw
                grid2.Paint -= drawdot;
                grid2.Paint += drawdot;
                grid2.Invalidate();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are invalidating the whole grid is redrawn, you should invalidate only the parts that you just redrawn. This is create a region and pass it to grid2.Invalidate as a parameter. Roughly it would look like something like this:

```
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        path.AddLines(points);
        lvResults.Invalidate(new Region(path));
```

UPDATE:

You could also keep a list of all the clicked points and call the imagedraw method once for each new points, just add a new item to the list when clicking on the object and you should be good to go. I don't know if you could get into some race condition scenario where someone clicks while it's trying to draw on all points but it would be easily handled if that was the case

Comment: Note that this is is just a stub and I'm assuming that you are using a poligon with straight lines between each point, maybe it's a square or something with rounded edges, you just need to create the region that you need and keep in mind that anything that you invalidate will be totally redrawn.

Comment: I did it by storing all the points in a list and using a foreach loop to draw the images. Thanks for the help!